# Quantum particle definition

Tags: quantum-mechanics, definition, elementary-particles

I'm reading a-lot of articles lately which mention "quantum particle" I was wandering what defines quantum particle in opposed to "regular particle"? from what I've read on the web, there are two answers:

1) a particle which cannot be divided any further

2) a particle which can be described using a wave function

I was wondering if there's any articles or somewhere to read more about it, in order to understand what it really means?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm reading a-lot of articles lately which mention "quantum particle" I was wandering what defines quantum particle in opposed to "regular particle"?

The opposition is between *quantum particle* and *classical particle* - the difference is really not between particles, but between the theories that we use to describe them (and how these particles are supposed to behave according to these theories.)

Answer (score 1):

What differs from a regular particle to quantum one is the uncertainty of knowing its location, in a theory that describes the behavior of the particle.

To further explain, I’d interpret the word “regular particle” as an object whose location in space is *assumed* to be able to be measured with infinite precision and accuracy without changing its state of motion. If an object is appeared to be occupying the space in a certain volume form rather than a tiny dot, then we can simply see the object as a set of dots, either that’s discrete (e.g., gas consists of individual particles) or continuous (e.g., rigid body or fluid) - either way, it could be thought of as a particle, fundamentally.

Such objects’ behavior can be well explained by applying classical physical laws, Newton’s laws of motion. On top of the laws, we could add more physical laws such as Lagrange-d’Alembert principle, and Hamilton’s principle.

In detail, we firstly model the reality as $n$-dimensional space with a handful of additional structures (such as metric, algebraic operations, measure, tangent space, etc) and translate the physical laws in the language of mathematics to apply them to our mathematical model. In classical mechanics, every point in the background $n$-manifold indicates the spatial coordinate of a particle[1] and the physical laws yield equations that precisely describe the behavior of “regular particles”.

In quantum mechanics, the story is fundamentally different. We could assume that what we observe is in the form of particle (like those tiny dots on the screen in the slit experiment), but the particles do not follow at all the classical laws - in particular, we happen to not be able to measure the location of the particles without changing their state of motion. We can’t even be sure if the objects we are studying are fundamentally dot-like, because they also happen to behave like waves.

Most elementarily, Schrödinger managed to formulate the equation to explain the behavior of such objects, but interpretations for the objects that the equation governs were (and still are) controversial. But the most widely accepted interpretation is that the solution has something to do with probabilities of detecting that object, the “quantum particle”.

[1]: Not always; there is something called Hamiltonian formulation which puts location and momentum on an equal footing, hence the background manifold is $2n$-dimensional with $n$-dimensional positions and $n$-dimensional momenta.

Comment: I fail to see how reality is modelled as an $n$-dimensional space classically, shouldn't space be $3$-dimensional? Even if one takes the generalisation to relativistic classical field theory, the background manifold aka spacetime is $4$ dimensional, regardless of whether your treatment is with Lagrangians or Hamiltonians.

Comment: The Hamiltonians and Lagrangians don't change the dimensions of the background as you describe in your footnote. They are merely functions defined on the cotangent bundle and the tangent bundle of the background manifold respectively.